# Is it possible to use map value in soql condition?

Tags: apex, soql

I need to perform soql query on the basis of value present in map.Can i do it??
If yes, please tell me how ?

Comment: using map.values() ??

Comment: Short answer is yes, better if you explain the issue a little more with appropriate code segments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example:**

```
Map<String,String> accountNameByPhone = new Map<String,String>{'111111' => 'Test Name'};
Account acs = [SELECT id,Name FROM Account WHERE Name in :accountNamesByPhone.values()];
```

Comment: @user123 - Please do not make it a habit of saying thanks as a comment but not marking the answer as completed

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can by using the values() method.
Eg. **delete** mapName.**values**();